# Copy a range from worksheet to google doc by replace text with table format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula

I want to copy a range cell from a worksheet to a google doc, keeping a table format

In a google doc template I added a text to be replaced.

**{{TablaDetalle}}**

I have a range for replace {{TablaDetalle}} and I get as

| Item | Equipo | Nro Serie | Sitio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 11 | Sitio A |
| 2 | AA | 22 | Sitio A |
| 3 | UPS | 88 | Sitio A |
| 4 | UPS | 99 | Sitio A |

A part of my code is

```
var hoja= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base Datos")
var wTablaDetalle=hoja.getRange("A1:D5").getDisplayValues()

function crearCoti() {
  //create a new document based on template and store on a temp folder

  var templateDoc=DriveApp.getFileById(wTemplateId); // 
  var blobTemplate=templateDoc.getBlob()

  var folderNewCoti=DriveApp.getFolderById(wfolderNewCoitId);
  var folderTemp=DriveApp.getFolderById(wfolderTempId);
  

  var copyArchivoPlantilla=templateDoc.makeCopy(folderTemp)
  
  // get id from new copy template created and open it
  var copyId= copyArchivoPlantilla.getId();
  var wcopyArchivoPlantilla=DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
    
  wcopyArchivoPlantilla.getBody().replaceText("{{TablaDetalle}}",wTablaDetalle)
```

of course, the text that be copied into google doc is

**Item,Equipo,Nro serie,Sitio,1,AA,11,Sitio A,2,AA,22,Sitio A,3,UPS,88,Sitio A,4,UPS,99,Sitio A**

Is there a way to copy the bellow data as a table or with any format ? By the way, the range to copy can get more or less rows, but always the same columns

I Wait for yours comments and thaks in advance

Omar

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I have an item 1 and value 1 already in my sheet, and then I get new value of item 1, I want to renew value 1 only, otherwise, if I get new item 2 and value 2, I want to add this in new columns.`. By this, I cannot imagine your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue of your script and your goal? And, can you provide your current script? For example, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to insert a table by replacing the marker paragraph.

I have provided 2 options, 1) looping through each paragraph looking for the specific text and 2) using `body.findText()`

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let data = [['Item','Equipo','Nro serie','Sitio'],
                [1,'AA',11,'Sitio A'],
                [2,'AA',22,'Sitio A'],
                [3,'UPS',88,'Sitio A'],
                [4,'UPS',99,'Sitio A']];
    let paras = body.getParagraphs();
    paras.some( para => {
        if( para.getText() === '{{TablaDetalle}}' ) {
          let index = body.getChildIndex(para);
          let table = body.insertTable(index,data);
          for( let i=0; i<table.getNumRows(); i++ ) {
            let row = table.getRow(i);
            for( let j=0; j<row.getNumCells(); j++ ) {
              let cell = row.getCell(j);
              if( i === 0 ) {
                cell.setBackgroundColor('#FFFF00');
              }
              cell.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            }
          }
          body.removeChild(para);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

As an alternative using the `body.findText()`

```
function test() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let data = [['Item','Equipo','Nro serie','Sitio'],
                [1,'AA',11,'Sitio A'],
                [2,'AA',22,'Sitio A'],
                [3,'UPS',88,'Sitio A'],
                [4,'UPS',99,'Sitio A']];
    let element = body.findText('{{TablaDetalle}}');
    if( element ) {
      element = element.getElement().getParent();
      let index = body.getChildIndex(element);
      let table = body.insertTable(index,data);
      for( let i=0; i<table.getNumRows(); i++ ) {
        let row = table.getRow(i);
        for( let j=0; j<row.getNumCells(); j++ ) {
          let cell = row.getCell(j);
          if( i === 0 ) {
            cell.setBackgroundColor('#FFFF00');
          }
          cell.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        }
      }
      body.removeChild(element);
    }
    else {
      console.log("not found");
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getActiveDocument())
- [Document.getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBody())
- [Body.getParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getParagraphs())
- [Body.getChildIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element))
- [Body.insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,String))
- [Body.removeChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removeChild(Element))
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)
- [Table Cell Horizontal Alignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-alignment)
- [TableCell.setBackgroundColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setBackgroundColor(String))
- [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String))

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to use a getrange from the sheat instaed fixed data, but I underestand yor answer concept . Thanks a lot again

Comment: Yes, It works ussing a dynamic data form a getRange. for example
getRange(9,4,5,4).getDisplayValues()....great !

Is there a way to give format to table rows...for example, the first row must be a header, with for exable other backgorund color, and the text on the all cells must be center aligned.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include code that will do what you requested.  If this answers your question please mark it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I have included a more efficient way of looking for the text string using `body.findText()`.